# Why is no ouput generated from this function?

Tags: python, pycharm

I have this python function and i wish to execute this using `lambda` handler function hence I have written this code. When I execute in Pycharm I don't see any output in console. Can someone guide what is the problem with below code?

```py
import json
from json import loads

import requests
from requests import exceptions
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    test_post_headers_body_json()
    return {"statusCode": 200, "body": json.dumps("Hello from Lambda!")}


def test_post_headers_body_json():
    client_id = "WJRYDHNGROIZHL8B"
    client_secret = "V5VXK6FLG1YI0GD2XY3H"
    user = "automation-store-admin1@abc.com"


    password = "c0Ba5PBdvVl2"

    access_point = "https://api.platform.abc.com/auth/oauth/token"
    grant_type = "password"

    headers = {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}

    # auth = auth.HTTPBasicAuth(client_id, client_secret)

    data = {"grant_type": grant_type, "username": user, "password": password}

    resp = None
    try:
        resp = requests.post(
            access_point,
            auth=HTTPBasicAuth(client_id, client_secret),
            data=data,
            headers=headers,
        )
    except exceptions.ConnectionError:
        exit(1)

    if resp.status_code == 200:
        resp = loads(resp.text)
        if "access_token" in resp:
            print(resp["access_token"])
            exit(0)

    exit(1)
```

Comment: Use the debugger to step through the code.

Comment: hopefully that isn't your real password... Anyways, do you ever run `lambda_handler`?

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Comment: FYI, you can use `resp.json` instead of `json.loads(resp.text)`

Comment: @AMC I think the rest of the code starting with `password =` is also supposed to be indented in the function.

Comment: @Barmar Yup, I have the fixed code, but there's a pending edit that I don't know how to handle. I literally just hit 2k rep, so I wasn't expecting the edit to go through instantly.

Comment: unfortunately still i dont get any output

Comment: @CarolynCordeiro _unfortunately still i dont get any output_ What is that in response to?

Comment: @AMC when i run the project in pycharm IDE , i get blank output ,i expect a token generated,i would expect a response from lambda_handler saying Hello from Lambda!

Answer (score 0):

It is normal because when running you code, Python only declare the function not using it. You should add a [`__main__` entry point](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html) at the end of your file:

```py
import json
from json import loads

import requests
from requests import exceptions
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    test_post_headers_body_json()
    return {"statusCode": 200, "body": json.dumps("Hello from Lambda!")}


def test_post_headers_body_json():
    client_id = "WJRYDHNGROIZHL8B"
    client_secret = "V5VXK6FLG1YI0GD2XY3H"
    user = "automation-store-admin1@abc.com"


    password = "c0Ba5PBdvVl2"

    access_point = "https://api.platform.abc.com/auth/oauth/token"
    grant_type = "password"

    headers = {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}

    # auth = auth.HTTPBasicAuth(client_id, client_secret)

    data = {"grant_type": grant_type, "username": user, "password": password}

    resp = None
    try:
        resp = requests.post(
            access_point,
            auth=HTTPBasicAuth(client_id, client_secret),
            data=data,
            headers=headers,
        )
    except exceptions.ConnectionError:
        exit(1)

    if resp.status_code == 200:
        resp = loads(resp.text)
        if "access_token" in resp:
            print(resp["access_token"])
            exit(0)

    exit(1)

# added part
if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_post_headers_body_json()
```

Comment: Its weird i still get blank response in Pycharm IDE :( i would expect a response from lambda_handler saying Hello from Lambda!

Comment: I got below output from AWS lambda Response:
{
  "errorMessage": "Bad handler 'SRE:lambda_handler': not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)",
  "errorType": "Runtime.MalformedHandlerName"
}

Request ID:
"a9293697-a1ea-4fea-bfcf-7603fe248973"
Handler name was SRE:lambda_handler